# What is the best way to replace all special characters with their full names in a String Java?

Tags: java

I want to convert all the special characters in a String to their full names.

**Example:**

Input: What is stack overflow?

Output: What is stack overflow question mark

I used `replaceall()` to do it, but is there any simpler way of doing it because I have to write one line for each special character?

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\.", " Fullstop ");
text = text.replaceAll("!", " Exclamation mark ");
text = text.replaceAll("\"", " Double quote ");
text = text.replaceAll("#", " Hashtag ");
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach here would be to maintain a hashmap containing all symbols and their name replacements.  Then, do a regex iteration over the input string and make all replacements.

```java
Map<String, String> terms = new HashMap<>();
terms.put(".", " Fullstop ");
terms.put("!", " Exclamation mark ");
terms.put("\"", " Double quote ");
terms.put("#", " Hashtag ");

String input = "The quick! brown #fox \"jumps\" over the lazy dog.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[.!\"#]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, terms.get(matcher.group(0)));
}
matcher.appendTail(buffer);

System.out.println("input:  " + input);
System.out.println("output: " + buffer.toString());
```

This prints:

```
input:  The quick! brown #fox "jumps" over the lazy dog.
output: The quick Exclamation mark  brown  Hashtag fox  Double quote jumps Double quote  over the lazy dog Fullstop
```

The above approach appears a bit verbose, but in practice all the core replacement logic is happening within a one line `while` loop.  If you are on Java 8, you could also use a `Matcher` stream approach, but the logic would be more or less the same.

Answer (score 1):

Look at built-in Unicode names:

```
    String s = "a!\".";
    s.codePoints()
            .filter(cp -> !Character.isAlphabetic(cp))
            .forEach(cp -> System.out.println(Character.getName(cp)));

EXCLAMATION MARK
QUOTATION MARK
FULL STOP
```

With a `toLowerCase`/capitalize you can have a fine complete & compact result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream`:

```
String text= "Input: What is stack overflow?";
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
    put("\\.", " Fullstop ");
    put("!", " Exclamation mark ");
    put("\"", " Double quote ");
    put("#", " Hashtag ");
    put("?", " question mark");
}};
System.out.println(
        Stream.of(text.split(""))
                .map(s -> map.getOrDefault(s,s))
                .collect(Collectors.joining())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

*using an* `IntStream` *allows to do it in one swoop*

```
String text= "Input: What is stack overflow?";
System.out.println(
    text.codePoints().mapToObj( c -> {
      switch( c ) {
      case '.':
        return "‹Fullstop›";
      case '!':
        return "‹Exclamation mark›";
      case '"':
        return "‹Double quote›";
      case '#':
        return "‹Hashtag›";
      case '?':
        return "‹Question mark›";
      default:
        return String.valueOf( (char)c );
      }
    } ).collect( StringWriter::new, StringWriter::write,
        ( w1, w2 ) -> w1.write( w2.toString() ) ).toString() );
```

*…or adapted with [Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen)'s idea (but keeping the original text)*

```
System.out.println(
    text.codePoints().collect( StringWriter::new,
        (w, c) -> w.write( Character.isAlphabetic( c )
            ? Character.toString( c ) : '‹' + Character.getName( c ) + '›'),
        ( w1, w2 ) -> w1.write( w2.toString() ) ).toString() );
```

gets: `Input‹COLON›‹SPACE›What‹SPACE›is‹SPACE›stack‹SPACE›overflow‹QUESTION MARK›`

Answer (score 0):

### You can do it in a single statement.

You can chain the string operations i.e. the result of one string operation can be passed to the next operation by chaining as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "He asked, \"What is Stackoverflow?\"\nHow beautiful!\nNeither am I the God nor am I the Devil.";
        
        text = text.replaceAll("\\.", " Fullstop ")
                .replaceAll("!", " Exclamation mark ")
                .replaceAll("\"", " Double quote ")
                .replaceAll("#", " Hashtag ");
        
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
He asked,  Double quote What is Stackoverflow? Double quote 
How beautiful Exclamation mark 
Neither am I the God nor am I the Devil Fullstop
```

Comment: This approach has the drawback that you must iterate the entire input string one time, for each symbol to be replaced, so it doesn't scale too well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I do not understand how you can avoid iterating the entire string for any symbol to be replaced e.g. if you have replaced the full stop in the entire string, you need to replace the exclamation mark again in the entire string. Isn't it? Even in your solution, `matcher.find()` scans the entire string. Please let me know if this is not correct.

Comment: My solution iterates the input string _once_, while in your solution each call to `replaceAll` will scan the input one time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - My comment was based on my understanding that `while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println("Hello");
   matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, terms.get(matcher.group(0)));
  }` will print `Hello` five times because `while (matcher.find())`  will iterate `5` times. I will analyse your answer and comment again when I have some time. Thanks for your feedback.